# Windows 10 - Driver issue

Tags: windows-10, touchpad, touchscreen, device-manager

I have a Lenovo Ideapad 5 15IIL05, that recently had its screen replaced, the device was ‘outta commission’ for roughly 2.5 months, after replacing the screen and doing the initial reboot, the following upgrades from win10 had caused the device to lose both touchscreen and precision touchpad drivers… I’ve spoken to both Microsoft & Lenovo… they’ve told me time and time again that a factory reset will fix the issue, but it will not and does not.

I’ve tried every listed fix I can find and have ran every diagnostic program/troubleshooter thru lenovo. SFC/ScanNow returns no issues, running DISM offline commands fixes minor bugs here and there, but nothing will restore my drivers.. & manually updating them is not working for me. I don’t know if I’m doing something wrong but I don’t want to mess up the device manager either.

I have tried retrieving the necessary drivers from manufacturers websites to no avail… they’ll install but then nothing happens.. even after a reboot.

As I have tried every fix listed on the internet, done all the manufacturers have asked of me… I’m at my wits end with this BS anymore… Lenovo wants me to pay $230 to reinstate & upgrade my warranty plan… I do not want to do that unless it’s 100% necessary as my laptop was in absolute MINT Condition before the screen replacement, it was purchased end of 2020 and only used a handful of times and stored in a laptop bag, up until Sept of 2022 when it became my daily device.

- I believe the issue at this point is either a hardware issue that 100% did not exist before the latest updates OR corrupt, missing or simply misplaced/unidentifiable drivers somewhere in the device manager.

I believe that I am in desperate need of assistance from an IT Genius who is well versed in both Lenovo products & the drivers they tend to use, as well as windows software and the drivers they’ve used in both Win10-Win11 OS… please someone, help me before I lose my mind.

Sincerely, a very overwhelmed, exhausted & frustrated business owner.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

First, there are [known issues](https://www.drivethelife.com/fix-lenovo-touchpad-not-working-windows-10/) with the Lenovo touchpad simply being *turned off* after a Windows update. Enable it in the Control Panel:  *Start Menu > Settings > Devices > Mouse & touchpad > Additional mouse options > Device Settings*. In *Devices*, enable the Lenovo touchpad. Buried a bit deep, there!

Also see the Lenovo [text and video for this issue](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/videos/vid500014-touchpad-not-working-in-windows-10-8-7).

Finally, if those don't hellp, one way to check if it's software (OS/drivers) or hardware issue: boot from another OS, such as a live Ubuntu USB. This does *not* require installation of any software. However, note that you might need to [add drivers manually](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1248176/ideapad-5-15are05-elan-touchpad-not-working-on-20-04-nor-on-18-04)!

Hopefully, it's just that single setting in Windows... please let us know if that resolves the issue.